# Slack Message Dialog's Curl Call

Tags: php, slack, slack-api

can anyone please give me an example of slack message dialog in PHP? How to make curl call to dialog.open method? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example in PHP of how to create a Dialog based on a slash command.

Note that you need to create and install a [Slack App](https://api.slack.com/slack-apps) first. You also need to add a [slash command](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands) to your Slack app, which needs to call this script. Finally you need to manually add the **OAuth Access Token** from your Slack app to this script (replace `YOUR_TOKEN`).

The script will print the API response in the Slack channel, so you can the response and if they are any errors.

Execute the slash command to run the dialog.

```
// define the dialog for the user (from Slack documentation example)
$dialog = [
  'callback_id' => 'ryde-46e2b0',
  'title' => 'Request a Ride',
  'submit_label' => 'Request',
  'elements' => [
    [
      'type' => 'text',
      'label' => 'Pickup Location',
      'name' => 'loc_origin'
    ],
    [
      'type' => 'text',
      'label' => 'Dropoff Location',
      'name' => 'loc_destination'
    ]
  ]
];

// get trigger ID from incoming slash request
$trigger = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "trigger_id");

// define POST query parameters
$query = [
    'token' => 'YOUR_TOKEN',
    'dialog' => json_encode($dialog),
    'trigger_id' => $trigger
];

// define the curl request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://slack.com/api/dialog.open');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// set the POST query parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($query));

// execute curl request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// close
curl_close($ch);

var_export($response);
```

Comment: @Pooja Nikam If this answer solved your questions, please consider marking it as solution. Thank you!

Comment: Thank You. This helps me a lot.

Comment: Awesome! Can you then please mark this answer as solution, so that the question can be closed?

Comment: I'm looking exactly the same for Node, just a normal request. I don't understand why Slack documentation is so confusing